# How can I make my id variable globally?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can somebody help me with how can I make my id variable globally? What is  wrong here?

```
var id;

function GenerateTableFromJson(objArray) {
    var tableContent =
        '<table id="FilesTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">' +
        '<thead><tr>' + '<th>ID</th>' + '<th>Actions</th>' + '</tr></thead>';
    for (var i = 0; i < objArray.length; i++) {
        tableContent += '<tr>';

        tableContent += '<td>' + objArray[i].Id + '</td>';

        tableContent += "<td><a id='" + objArray[i].Id + "' href='#' style='color: orange' class='confirmEditFileLink'>" +
            "<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil' title='Edit Item'></i></a>&nbsp&nbsp";
        tableContent += "<a id='" + objArray[i].Id + "' href='#' style='color: red' class='confirmDeleteFileLink'>" +
            "<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove' title='Delete File'></i></a>&nbsp&nbsp";
        tableContent += "<a id='" + objArray[i].Id + "' href='#' class='confirmListItemDetailsLink'>" +
            "<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-cog' title='Link to List Item'></i></a></td>";
        tableContent += '</tr>';
        var intmaxId = objArray[i].Id;
        id = intmaxId;
        //windows.id = intmaxId;
        return id;
    }
    return tableContent;
};
console.log(id);
```

Comment: how can you say that your `id` is not global?

Comment: chek Arun Sivan answers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 var id;
 var idArray=[];
 var tableContent;

 function GenerateTableFromJson(objArray){      

    tableContent = '<table id="FilesTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">' +
    '<thead><tr>' + '<th>ID</th>' + '<th>Actions</th>' + '</tr></thead>';

     for (var i = 0; i < objArray.length; i++) {

     tableContent += '<tr>';
     tableContent += '<td>' + objArray[i].Id + '</td>';
     tableContent += "<td><a id='" + objArray[i].Id + "' href='#' style='color: orange' class='confirmEditFileLink'>" +
        "<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil' title='Edit Item'></i></a>&nbsp&nbsp";
    tableContent += "<a id='" + objArray[i].Id + "' href='#' style='color: red' class='confirmDeleteFileLink'>" +
        "<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove' title='Delete File'></i></a>&nbsp&nbsp";
    tableContent += "<a id='" + objArray[i].Id + "' href='#' class='confirmListItemDetailsLink'>" +
        "<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-cog' title='Link to List Item'></i></a></td>";
    tableContent += '</tr>';
    idArray.push(objArray[i].Id);

    }
    return tableContent;
}
tableContent=GenerateTableFromJson(objArray);
console.log(idArray);
```

In this sample code id, idArray and tableContent are defined globally. In every iteration your id will be pushed to an array so that you can get entire data after completion of iteration.

if you need find max id then you can use `var max = Math.max(...arr);`

I also suggest you to use following pattern while creating element rather than appending strings.
`var table=$("<table>");` or
`var table=document.createElement('table');`   which will increase flexibility and readability.

Comment: Wow! Thank you it's working, but when i need max id i get infinity

Comment: Here is example for reducing array to find largest number try this.`var arr = [1,2,3];
var max = arr.reduce(function(a, b) {
    return Math.max(a, b);
});`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that code is at the top level of the script, your `id` variable **is** global. But it only has its default value (`undefined`) at the point where you `console.log` it, because the only code that assigns it a value is in the `GenerateTableFromJson` function, which nothing in that code calls. Until/unless something calls `GenerateTableFromJson`, `id` won't have a value.

---

There are other issues, such as the fact that your `for` loop will only ever run once, since you're doing a `return` from within it, which will exit the function.